# Discord.py Time Schedule

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Is there a better way to create a alarm clock in python than the one I'm using in my code? It is working fine but I wonder if there is something better , also I want to separate this code and make it in to a cog....

```
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = 'XXX'

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')

alarm_time = '23:33'#24hrs
channel_id = '51599XXXXX5036697'

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot Online.')


async def time_check():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    while not client.is_closed:
        now = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%H:%M')
        channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)
        messages = ('Test')
        if now == alarm_time:
           await client.send_message(channel, messages)
             time = 90
        else:
           time = 1
        await asyncio.sleep(time)


client.loop.create_task(time_check())

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 3):

What you could do is use the [`sched`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html), for example:

```
import time
import sched
s = sched.scheduler(time.perf_counter, time.sleep)
s.enter(60, 1, action_function, (args))
s.run()
```

The code above starts a scheduler as `s`, which uses `time.perf_couter` to get the current time, and `time.sleep` for doing the delay.

When you use the scheduler you need to pass it at least 3 arguments, the first being the daly time in seconds, the second being it's priority (scheduled events with the highest prioroty are executed first, and the third argument is the function to be executed after the delay.

There can be two more optional arguments being a tuple of arguments, or a dict of keyword arguments, both of these arguments will get passed to the function that will be executed after the delay.

I have used this same library for implementing things such as timed bans within IRC bots, so it should also be applicable to your Discord bot.

Here is an example that should work (I don't use discord and such so don't can't really test the whole code, just snippets) using your code:

```
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from discord.ext import commands
import time
import sched

TOKEN = 'XXX'

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')

alarm_time = '23:33'#24hrs
channel_id = '51599XXXXX5036697'

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot Online.')


async def time_check():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    while not client.is_closed:
        channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)
        messages = ('Test')
        f = '%H:%M'

        now = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), f)
        # get the difference between the alarm time and now
        diff = (datetime.strptime(alarm_time, f) - datetime.strptime(now, f)).total_seconds()

        # create a scheduler
        s = sched.scheduler(time.perf_counter, time.sleep)
        # arguments being passed to the function being called in s.enter
        args = (client.send_message(channel, message), )
        # enter the command and arguments into the scheduler
        s.enter(seconds, 1, client.loop.create_task, args)
        s.run() # run the scheduler, will block the event loop


client.loop.create_task(time_check())

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: can u show me how to appliy it  in my code, if it is not to much to ask. I'm new to this.

Comment: I've edited the post with an example using you're code that should work, it will only create one alarm event that will be executed at that time, if you want to start more you would need to do some more editing.

Comment: I did try the code you gave me , I did a little research too. on f = '%M:%M' it should be f = '%H:%M', right?? so I can get the seconds. Also after the part of create the scheduler it get stuck

Comment: Task exception was never retrieved
        Bot Online.

Comment: AttributeError: module 'asyncio' has no attribute 'create_task'

Comment: Sorry 'bout that, didn't see that you were using client.loop.create_task, I replaced it with that so give it a go now.

Comment: Also it is '%H'%M' because that is the format you used in alarm_time, if you wanted seconds you would have to change it to '%H:%M:%S', but you might also have to change `time_format` at the top to add seconds.

Comment: seconds = timedelta(hour=diff.hour, minute=diff.minute).total_seconds() I have a problem with this line

Comment: even if I bypass (seconds) problem   and do it manually like (seconds = 5) trying to test it. nothing is happening for 5 seconds not even an error, bot is just waiting.....

Comment: I've made another edit and it's working for me, if you have any other problems you should try to work through them yourself. And if you're this new with python, maybe creating your own asyncronous bot isnt the way to go, maybe try using one already made and just tinkering with it.