# How do I use schedule py and Discord py together?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, discord.py, schedule

Main goal:
Send a message to a channel every **Wednesday at 08:00**

This is my current code:

```
import schedule
import time
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from discord.ext.tasks import loop

client = discord.Client()

# IMPORTANT
channel = 
botToken = ""

async def sendloop():
  while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
        general_channel = client.get_channel(channel)
        print('ready')
        schedule.every(2).seconds.do(lambda:loop.create_task(general_channel.send('TEST')))

client.run(botToken)
```

So far, there are no errors, just stuck on "ready". I am a beginner using **VS Code.**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Did you mean to call `sendloop()` somewhere?

Comment: Hello, @Coder-256! I'm gonna be honest, this was a solution I got from the discord.py server on Discord.

In the official schedule py documentation, the while loop could stand on its own. 

I had no idea why he had to create a function for that.

https://pypi.org/project/schedule/

Comment: It looks like the purpose of the `sendloop()` function is to run asynchronously, but it shouldn't make much of a difference, either way works. If you choose this way, I think you need to add something like `asyncio.run(sendloop())` to the bottom of the file.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using scheduler, since discord the extension `task` which can do the same as what you are trying to implement in your code:

```
from discord.ext import commands, tasks

ch = id_channel
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')
TOKEN = "Token"

#every week at this time, you can change this to seconds=2 
#to replicate what you have been testing
@tasks.loop(hours=168) 
async def every_wednesday():
    message_channel = client.get_channel(ch)
    await message_channel.send("Your message")

@every_wednesday.before_loop
async def before():
    await client.wait_until_ready()

every_wednesday.start()

client.run(TOKEN)
```

If you were to run this code on the time you want it to be repeated, it will accomplish what you want. Another approach is checking on the `before()` function to check if it is the right time to run if you don't want to wait and run the code on the day you want this to run.

But if you really want to use the schedule module, this post my help you:  [Discord.py Time Schedule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53755103/discord-py-time-schedule/53757482)